# Deleting same-called subfolders

Tags: directory, command, delete

I have the following dir structure:

```
/Simulation-1/results/...
/Simulation-1/model/...
/Simulation-2/results/...
/Simulation-2/model/...
...
/Simulation-N/results/...
/Simulation-N/model/...
```

with $N$ being a very large number. I would like to delete all 'model' subfolders (but not the other files/dirs in the Simuluation folder). Is there a handy command I could use? It would need to recursively search through all folders (all simulation folders in particular). I appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to U/L! Would something like `rm -r */model` work? Test it on a dummy tree first. Also, the leading `/` in your paths is strange. Did you really want that there?

Comment: If some of them are more than two levels down then you can also use `find /directory -mindepth 2 -type d -name model -delete`. You can run it without `-delete` beforehand to make sure that it's only returning the directories that you want.